# How do I override the ViewModel DataContext so I can bind to objects in the View (Mvvm-Light)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I am using Mvvm-Light and have been ignoring how binding in XAML really works up until now.

Here's my XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,14">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="{Binding SecuritySystemName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding PageName}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock Name="textCode" 
        DataContext="{WHAT GOES HERE to bind to properties on my View (SecurityPanelPage class)}"    
        Text="{Binding Path=Code}" />

</Grid>
```

{Binding SecuritySystemName} and {Binding PageName} correctly bind to my ViewModel (SecuirtyPanelViewModel).  But I want {Binding Code} in the TextBlock element to bind to my VIEW (not ViewModel).

I have searched and searched for documentation & samples that explain the syntax and values supported by DataContext and Binding.  Nothing has helped.

All I want to know is how do I set a DataContext (or specify something in a {Binding ...} that will point to my View object.  I've tried "Self" and all sorts of "RelativeSource" things, but none work.  Guessing is not productive because the round trip into the debugger before the XAML is parsed is too long.

Thanks.

UPDATE - I found AN answer that gets me moving, but I still don't grok so I have follow up questions for the fine posters below..

Here's what works:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Name="ThisPage">
   <TextBlock Name="textCode" Text="{Binding Code, ElementName=ThisPage"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I found this hint here: http://bursjootech.blogspot.com/2007/12/bind-from-xaml-to-local-property-in.html

He asked the question differently: how to "Bind from XAML to a local property in code-behind".

I still don't understand the two solutions provided below.  So more questions below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically when you're using MVVM nearly all of your bindable properties are on your ViewModel and not on your Views.  However, obviously sometimes you want to create component controls which do have properties.  Can you explain what the property is and why it needs to only be a property on the view?

That being said ... I'm guessing your SecurityPanelPage is the view for the XAML displayed?

You can give your control a name and then use ElementName binding.  This way you do not need to set the DataContext.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
  x:Name="controlName"
  x:Class="SomeNamespace.SecurityPanelPage">
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And then your binding changes to:

```
<TextBlock
  Name="textCode" 
  Text="{Binding Path=Code, ElementName=controlName}" />
```

To explicitly set the DataContext you can do the following:

```
<TextBlock
  Name="textCode" 
  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=controlName}"
  Text="{Binding Path=Code}" />
```

Comment: Ok, when I first read your answer I didn't grok it.  I thought you were suggesting something different and your sample wasn't complete.  But now I see you are providing the same solution I found above.

Comment: Let me ask a follow up:  In the example using DataContext, what other syntax of DataContext will get to the root?  I swear I saw something before but can't remember.

Comment: Oh, and you are right about this stuff belonging in my ViewModel. I was being lazy and then I got distracted by wanting to know how to do this.  I'm now moving all the code back to my VM where it belongs.

Comment: In Silverlight, the only other built-in option is RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, though you can only use that in a control template.  Silverlight 5 should introduce the ability to use RelativeSource based on an AncestorType, which allows the binding to walk up the VisualTree and find a specific type.  That is how it's typically done in WPF.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If i'm correct, you can add a resources in your app.xaml to the view you want.

A.E:

```
xmlns:crap="clr-namespace:Application.Views"
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <crap:MyViewPage x:Key="MyViewPage" />
    </ResourceDictionary>  
</Application.Resources>
```

then use it like `"{Binding MyProperty, source={StaticResource MyViewPage}".`

Hope this works / helps

Comment: How would I do the same thing using <phone:ApplicationPage.Reosoures> in my view's XAML. I can't figure out how to define the equivalent "xmlns:crap" for my view.

Comment: The "Application.Views" is the Views directory in my application.
But I do believe, if you want to bind to objects in the xaml, then joe mcBride's solution is better